# correct syntax for deducing return value of static member function of dependent type

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I can't figure out the correct syntax for deducing return value of static member function of dependent type. I've already tried a dozen of combinations, including use of ::std::result_of and none of them seem to work. Here is the variant that looks most promising (at least works in non-template context):

```cpp
struct
t_In
{
};

struct
t_Out
{
    static auto
    Method(t_In &) -> t_Out
    {
        return(t_Out());
    }
};

template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In, typename tp_Enable = void> struct
t_Template;

template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In> struct
t_Template
<
    tp_Out
,   tp_In
,   typename ::std::enable_if
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            decltype
            (
                ::std::remove_cv // adding typename here makes Method look like type
                <
                    typename ::std::remove_reference
                    <
                        tp_Out
                    >::type
                >::type::Method(::std::declval<tp_In>()) // Err: does not evaluate to function ...
            )
        ,   tp_Out
        >::value
    >::type
>
{
};
```

Edit: compiler VS2013, note that I don't even instantiate anything, error popup just from this template alone

Comment: does it work with `std::declval<tp_In&>()` ?

Comment: @ Piotr Skotnicki no, error message remains the same

Comment: @trbvm where is this "error message" ?

Comment: @ Bo Persson doing so leads to additional errors "'Method' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template"

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki just where the // Err: comment is

Comment: ... and what follows "does not evaluate to function"... ? how do you instantiate your `t_Template`, which compiler do you use ?

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki complete message is "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments", nothing else (this is VS2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr; type::StaticMemberFunctionName syntax in VS2013 is broken when used in template parameters, fancy expressions like decltype(decltype(*&tp_Out::Method)(::std::declval())) even lead to internal compiler errors.
However this syntax still works when used anywhere else, so I've managed to find a workaround:

```cpp
template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In> struct
t_MethodReturnValueDeducer
{
    typedef decltype
    (
        ::std::remove_cv
        <
            typename ::std::remove_reference
            <
                tp_Out
            >::type
        >::type::Method(::std::declval<tp_In &>())
    ) t_Deduced; 
};

template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In, typename tp_Enable = void> struct
t_Template;

template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In> struct
t_Template
<
    tp_Out
,   tp_In
,   typename ::std::enable_if
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            typename t_MethodReturnValueDeducer<tp_Out, tp_In>::t_Deduced
        ,   tp_Out
        >::value
    >::type
>
{

};
```

I hope this will be helpful for people still struggling with VS2013...

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that `std::declval` returns an rvalue reference, which cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference like `t_In&`.

A fairly clean solution is to use `void_t` and `std::declval<tp_In&>`:

```
//standard void_t implementation
template <typename...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename...Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

//primary template
template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In, typename tp_Enable = void>
struct t_Template;

//for when tp_Out has a static member function called Method 
//taking an lvalue reference to tp_In
template<typename tp_Out, typename tp_In>
struct t_Template
<tp_Out, tp_In, void_t<decltype(tp_Out::Method(std::declval<tp_In&>()))>>
{
};
```

Comment: FYI: OP uses MSVC (2013!)

Comment: Ah, yeah, MSVC doesn't support expression SFINAE, so this won't work unless OP switches compiler.

Comment: This leads to the same "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments". note that I don't even instantiate anything.

Comment: I think these are issues with MSVC. It [works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd2b90bc30ea0e39) in clang.

Comment: @ TartanLlama seem soo